# Comparing NDWI regions with a given shapefile Google Earth Engine Python?

Tags: python, shapefile, google-earth-engine, ndvi, normalized-difference-water-index

With the code below, I computed the NDVI, NDWI and NDWIMOD indices of a R.O.I. in order to detect water areas in that R.O.I.

Now, my goal concerns to compare the water areas with a given shapefile in order to find which areas are correctly detected by computing the indices. I want to do it for each index separately.

Do you have any advice about how I can carry out it? Moreover, How can I save the new areas detected?

The code is the following:

```py
import ee
import ee.mapclient

ee.Initialize()
ee.mapclient.centerMap(15.88, 41.78, 10)

def maskS2clouds(collection): 
    qa = collection.select('QA60')
    cloudBitMask = 1 << 10
    cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11
    mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0))
    return collection.updateMask(mask).divide(10000)

polygon = ee.Geometry.Polygon([[
[16.440171600655958,42.033470726105556], 
[15.511826874093458,42.12316884368949],
[14.621934295968458,41.689821328579825],
[15.441789032296583,41.00320702735848],
[16.246537567452833,41.36906568596335],
[16.440171600655958,42.033470726105556]]])

collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2').filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20)).filterDate('2018-01-1','2018-06-30').map(maskS2clouds).filterBounds(polygon)

medianpixel = collection.median()
medianpixelclipped = medianpixel.clip(polygon)

ndvi = collection.mean().normalizedDifference(['B8','B4'])
ndviViz = {'min':0.6, 'max': 1, 'palette': ['0000FF', 'FF0000']}
ndvimasked = ndvi.updateMask(ndvi.lt(0.0))
ee.mapclient.addToMap(ndvimasked, ndviViz, 'Sentinel_2 mosaic')

ndwi2 =  collection.mean().normalizedDifference(['B3','B8'])
ndwi2Viz = {'min': -0.4, 'max': 0.0, 'palette': ['FF0000', '00FF00']}
ndwi2masked = ndwi2.updateMask(ndwi2.gt(-0.125))
ee.mapclient.addToMap(ndwi2masked, ndwi2Viz, 'Sentinel_2 mosaic')

ndwi2mod = collection.mean().normalizedDifference(['B8','B3'])
ndwi2modViz = {'min': 0.0, 'max': 0.4, 'palette': ['FFFFFF', 'FF0000']}
ndwi2modmasked = ndwi2mod.updateMask(ndwi2mod.lt(0.0))
ee.mapclient.addToMap(ndwi2modmasked, ndwi2modViz, 'Sentinel_2 mosaic')

capitanata = ee.FeatureCollection('users/vpaparella96/vasche_puglia')
ee.mapclient.addToMap(capitanata)
```

I shared to everyone the shapefile.